# Python subprocess and running script on directory

Tags: python, pyqt, subprocess

Im trying to run subprocess.  Im running a python file on a directory (to convert each file in the directory.)  The convertor works and ive been implementing this into a gui(PYQT4).  Here is what I got so far:

```
def selectFile(self):



    self.listWidget.clear() # In case there are any existing elements in the list
    directory = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,
                                                       "Pick a folder")


    if directory:
        for file_name in os.listdir(directory):
            if file_name.endswith(".csv"):
                self.listWidget.addItem(file_name)
                print (file_name)




def convertfile(self, directory):

    subprocess.call(['python', 'Createxmlfromcsv.py', directory], shell=True)
```

The error im getting is ..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eeamesX/PycharmProjects/Workmain/windows.py", line 162, in convertfile
    subprocess.call(['python', 'Createxmlfromcsv.py', directory], shell=True)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

Any help for a beginner is appreciated :)

Comment: why are you using shell=True?

Comment: what is `type(directory)`? [don't use a list argument and `shell=True` on Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2400878/4279).

Comment: ok removed shell = True :/  The directory is for all csv files in a directory.  Want to run the script on them and convert them using a GUI and button

Comment: i don't think `QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory` returns what you think it does

Comment: Im not a PYQT expert by no means, i presumed it would select a directory

Comment: If you `print(directory)` you will see for yourself

Comment: ahh it printed the path

Comment: i changed directory to file_name in convertfile..still no luck :(

Comment: how are you calling `convertfile`? Also you can simply pass the content of `glob.iglob(os.path.join(directory,"*.csv"))` to find all csvs

Comment: # Open a FILE and append to screen
        self.selectFileButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Select Files', self)
        self.selectFileButton.move(135, 200)
        self.selectFileButton.clicked.connect(self.selectFile)




    # convert files
        self.convertButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Convert!', self)
        self.convertButton.move(350,350)
        self.convertButton.clicked.connect(self.convertfile)

Comment: # Open a FILE and append to screen
        self.selectFileButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Select Files', self)
        self.selectFileButton.move(135, 200)
        self.selectFileButton.clicked.connect(self.selectFile)




    # convert files
        self.convertButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Convert!', self)
        self.convertButton.move(350,350)
        self.convertButton.clicked.connect(self.convertfile)

Comment: How are you passing the directory?

Comment: I was doing it as file_name.  I wanted the script to be dynamic, rather than absolute paths.  Right now I am trying absolute paths to see if I can get it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments to the question, the line:

```
    self.convertButton.clicked.connect(self.convertfile)
```

will send `False` to the `convertfile` method when the button is clicked, which is why you see that error.

You need to add some code to `convertfile` which gets the directory path from the selected item in the list-widget. Something like:

```
    item = self.listWidget.currentItem()
    if item is not None:
        directory = unicode(item.text())
        subprocess.call(['python', 'Createxmlfromcsv.py', directory])
```

But note that you are not storing the full directory path in the list-widget, and so the subprocess call may fail. You should really add items to the list-widget like this:

```
    self.listWidget.addItem(os.path.join(directory, file_name))
```

Answer (score -1):

In "subprocess.call(['python', 'Createxmlfromcsv.py', directory], shell=True)", the 'directory' variable is not a String.