# Retrieve a value from subprocess after kill()

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, sys

So a bit of an odd project where I'm attempting to use a subprocess to keep track of the number of keys I press to measure my productivity.

Currently I start the subprocess using an Amazon Dash button, then kill the process on the second press.

```
def start_keylogger():
    global process
    process = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "python", "test.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

def stop_keylogger():
    os.killpg(process.pid, signal.SIGUSR1)
    process.wait()
    key_press_count = process.stdout.read()
    return key_press_count
```

From there my keylogger hasn't been fleshed out quite yet, but I think I would like to use `sys.exit()` or `exit()` to return the number of key presses.

```
def exit_and_return_counter():
    sys.stdout.write(current_keypress_counter)
    exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, exit_and_return_counter)
    try:
        while 1:
           main_loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit()
```

Initially I tried to use `process.returncode`, but it only returned `1`, I'm assuming the successful exit code. And I can't use `stdout, stderr  = process.communicate()` unless I want to keep the keylogger a short while after the second Amazon button press.

Comment: You can only get the return code if the process exits normally with `exit(code)`. WHen you kill it, the process exits due to the signal, and doesn't get to send an exit code.

Comment: BTW, on Unix the largest possible exit code is `255`. So your technique is not useful if you might type more than that many keys.

Comment: @Barmar: even if the process has been kill; you can get the return code (`rc = process.wait()` -- it is probably `-9` (corresponds to `SIGKILL`)). Though OP's code has other issues.

Comment: there are multiple issues in your code e.g., (1) It is pointless to import `call` if you need `subprocess.Popen` (2) [don't use `shell=True` and the list argument together on Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2400878/4279) (3) `global` inside `stop_keylogger()` is unnecessary (there is no assignment) (4) `process.kill()` won't kill the whole process tree, see [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4789837/4279) (5) KeyboardInterrupt won't catch SIGKILL (6) as @Barmar said: exit status range might be too small

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian But you can't return a **specific** code using `sys.exit()` if the process is killed.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the help @Barmar and @J.F. Sebastian. So I guess the better question would be how should I stop the process so I could use `exit(code)` to retrieve the value.

 I'm considering, while I think it's not the greatest idea, only running the keylogger for fixed intervals, say five minutes, and then adding the results together.

Comment: you should fix one issue at a time. You could start by following the links from my previous comment.

Comment: @BraedenYoung You could send a signal that doesn't kill the process, like `SIGUSR1`. And the signal handler in the keylogger can then do an ordinary exit. Or use a real inter-process communication mechanism like a pipe to tell the keylogger to exit.

Comment: Sorry @J.F.Sebastian I thought I had. 

Anyhow, following along with the stream of comments it looks like the best way to go about this would be to use `SIGUSR1` and handle the exit in the keylogger script.  I assumed that it would still be something along the lines of `process.returncode` but that only results in a None. I imagine I may not be handling the the `SIGUSR1` right in my keylogger script.

Comment: @Barmar the process isn't killed, it terminates normally. `SIGUSR1` is catched and thus doesn't kill the process. The `sys.exit(code)` terminates it.

Comment: @cg909 `SIGUSR1` wasn't in the question when I made my comment, he edited the question today to add it.

Comment: I've missed that you've updated the question two days ago. (1) don't use `PIPE` unless you consume the corresponding pipe otherwise you may hang the child process. [Use `DEVNULL` if you need to disgard the output](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11269575/4279) (2) if there is no `shell=True` then you don't need `os.killpg()` (and it is wrong without `preexec_fn=os.setpgrp`) (3) why do you need a subprocess here instead of [importing the module and using its functions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30165768/4279)

Comment: @Barmar ok, you're right I didn't see that. It seems at first that the OP mixed what will happen on `.kill()` and when `KeyboardInterrupt` is catched. His first version would have worked with `.send_signal(SIGINT)`

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian, (1) ah, good to know, I'm using it now in my answer below. (2) That's probably why I was struggling, it seemed like it would hang. (3) Since I have a main loop checking for new arps, and a another main loop recording key presses. I imagine I could have reworked it so I conditionally record key presses, but this seemed a lot easier. This also allows me to play with other keyloggers easily, or even swap out other python modules if I was to make an generic api to return a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not an elegant answer, using `process.send_signal(signal.SIGUSR1)` worked (as mentioned by @cg909). In the stop method we have:

```
def stop_keylogger():
    process.send_signal(signal.SIGUSR1)
    process.wait()
    return process.stderr.read()
```

Then in the key logger to handle the signal we have:

```
def exit_and_return_counter(*args):
    sys.stdout.write('%s'%counter)
    exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, exit_and_return_counter)
    try:
        while 1:
            main_loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply run
`process.wait()` after `os.killpg(process.pid, signal.SIGUSR1)`. This waits for the process to end and returns the status code. As you killed it just moments before, it won't block for long. Catching the USR1 signal and using `sys.exit` to change the code returned from the child should work.

You should also be able to read stdout with `process.stdout.read()` even after the child was killed, as the pipe created for the inter-process communication will live at least as long as the Popen object `process` exists.

Comment: So waiting on the process definitely seemed to be an issue, but I'm not getting anything back from `exit(current_keypress_count)`. I'm assuming I must not be handling `signal.SIGUSR1` right. Just to be clear, `process.stdout.read()` wasn't returning anything and `process.returncode` was 1

Comment: Try removing `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` from your Popen call. Then you can see the Python exceptions your subprocess is throwing. :-) I found the following issues: a signal callback must accept two parameters: the signal number and a stack frame, so: `exit_and_return_counter(signo, frame):` and `sys.stdout.write()` needs a string, so use sys.stdout.write(str(current_keypress_counter)). Also on my computer `os.killpg()` didn't work. `process.send_signal(signal.SIGUSR1)` worked for me.

Comment: Awesome, yeah I was able to handle the `SIGUSR1` when sent with `process.send_signal(signal.SIGUSR1)`. I put my changes in an answer below. Thanks for the help @cg909

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SIGINT` signal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal) to signal the process to print statistics and exit. You could handle `SIGINT` using `KeyboardInterrupt` exception handler:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#file: keylogger.py
import random
import time

counter = 0

def mainloop()
    global counter
    while True:
        counter += 1
        time.sleep(random.random())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        mainloop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt: # on SIGINT
        print(counter)
```

And here's the corresonding controller:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import signal
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, DEVNULL

process = None

def start_keylogger():
    global process
    stop_keylogger(expect_process_running=False)
    process = Popen(["python", "-m", "keylogger"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=DEVNULL,
                    preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)

def stop_keylogger(expect_process_running=True):
    global process
    if process is not None and process.poll() is None:
        os.killpg(process.pid, signal.SIGINT)
        counter = int(process.communicate()[0])
        process = None
        return counter
    if expect_process_running:
        raise RuntimeError('keylogger is not running')
```

You could emulate sending `SIGINT` when you run `keylogger.py` in the terminal (for testing/debugging) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

`preexec_fn=os.setpgrp` creates a separate process group. `os.killpg()` sends it the signal. If your `keylogger.py` does not spawn its own child processes when `preexec_fn=os.setpgrp` is unnecessary and it is enough to call `process.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)` instead of `os.killpg()`.

Consider [importing the keylogger module and using its functions instead of using `subprocess`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30165768/4279).