# How to execute 'ssconvert' command using subprocess

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, ssconvert

I want to execute the following command:

```
ssconvert /data/sam.xls,/data/test.csv
```

I have tried:

```
 p = subprocess.Popen(["ssconvert", '/data/sam.xls','/data/test.csv'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
   out = p.communicate()
   print"output", out
```

but it's not working.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `p = subprocess.Popen(["ssconvert", '/data/sam.xls,/data/test.csv'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)`?

Comment: i am getting error call over
Aborted (core dumped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is worked

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["ssconvert","sample.xlsx","sample.csv"],cwd="pathtoyourfile") # pathtoyourfile must contain the xlsx and csv files
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct command is not `ssconvert /data/sam.xls,/data/test.csv`. [It should be](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/ssconvert.1.html): `ssconvert /data/sam.xls /data/test.csv` instead (note: the space, not comma between the input and output filenames).

If you use `shell=True` then you should pass the command as a string. There is no need to use `shell=True` in this case. If `shell=False` (default) then each command-line argument should be passed as a single list item:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(['ssconvert', '/data/sam.xls', '/data/test.csv'])
```

See [Why subprocess.Popen doesn't work when args is sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2400878/4279)