# Run a .bat file in Windows using Python code?

Tags: python, batch-file

I try to run a `.bat` file in Windows using Python script.

`ask.bat` file:

```
Application.exe work.xml
```

I write Python code:

```py
import os
os.system("D:\xxx1\xxx2XMLnew\otr.bat ")
```

Output: when try to run the file its just give a blink of the command prompt, and the work is not performing.

Note: I try with alternate slashes also, but it is not working.

Comment: Did you try escaping the backslash? Try: `os.system("D:\\xxx1\\xxx2XMLnew\\otr.bat ")`

Comment: use / instead of \ if you dont want to escape it

Comment: You just need to add a r before the quote: r"D:\\xxx1\\xxx2XMLnew\\otr.bat "  
Try:  
`import os`  
`os.system(r"D:\xxx1\xxx2XMLnew\otr.bat ")`

Answer (score 54):

This has already been answered in detail on SO. Check out this thread, It should answer all your questions:
[Executing a subprocess fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818774/python-subprocess)

I've tried it myself with this code:

**batchtest.py**

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen("batch.bat", cwd=r"C:\Path\to\batchfolder")
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

**batch.bat**

```
echo Hello World!
pause
```

I've got the batchtest.py example from the aforementioned thread.

Comment: Hi das_weezul, Thanks for the info., i try what is mentioned there but for me the same problem persists, on executing,a blink of the app. is coming then went out, no work perform

Comment: while running this code i came around an error:" Windows Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified", but the file path is correct 100% i switch the folder location to test what u said.... code is     from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen("test.bat", cwd=r"C:\XMLnew")
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

Comment: @Silver: `Popen()` can't find the `test.bat` file. In the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html?highlight=popen#subprocess.Popen) it says "If *cwd* is not `None`, the child’s current directory will be changed to *cwd* before it is executed. Note that this directory is not considered when searching the executable, so you **can’t** specify the program’s path relative to *cwd*."

Comment: @martineau He used the path "C:\XMLnew" which is absolute, so that shouldn't be the problem

Comment: @das_weezul: Yes, but the `"test.bat"` is relative.

Comment: Can you not just call the content of the batch file from subprocess.Popen, it seems like a unessisary step

Comment: How would you go about passing an argument to the batch file in this format?

Comment: Agreed it's a bit of an annoyance setting the absolute `cwd` AND the path to the bat file. I suggest storing the path in a variable then re-using that variable within the code. `from subprocess import Popen
dir = fr'C:\path\bat_file_folder'
p = Popen(fr"{dir}\test_bat.bat", cwd=dir)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()`

Answer (score 34):

```
import subprocess

filepath="D:/path/to/batch/myBatch.bat"
p = subprocess.Popen(filepath, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print p.returncode # is 0 if success
```

Comment: `shell=True` is what allows you to run a .bat file instead of an .exe.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone no, it's not. You can call a .bat file from Popen without passing shell=True, but as martineau noted in the answer above, you _must_ specify the absolute path to the .bat file.

Answer (score 16):

Replace \ with / in the path

```
import os
os.system("D:/xxx1/xxx2XMLnew/otr.bat ")
```

Comment: i recommend using os.path.normpath
    filepath="D:/xxx1/xxx2XML/otr.bat"
    p = Popen(filepath, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
    
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    print process.returncode # is 0 if success

Answer (score 6):

Probably the simplest way to do this is ->

```
import os
os.chdir("X:\Enter location of .bat file")
os.startfile("ask.bat")
```

Comment: Not sure about other operating systems, but works on windows :)

Answer (score 5):

1. It is better to write `.bat` file in such way that its running is not dependent on current working directory, i.e. I recommend to put this line at the beginning of `.bat` file:

   ```
   cd "%~dp0"
   ```
2. Enclose filepath of `.bat` file in double quotes, i.e.:

   ```
   os.system('"D:\\x\\so here can be spaces\\otr.bat" ["<arg0>" ["<arg1>" ...]]')
   ```
3. To save output of some batch command in another file you can use usual [redirection syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), for example:

   ```
   os.system('"...bat" > outputfilename.txt')
   ```

   Or directly in your `.bat` file:

   ```
   Application.exe work.xml > outputfilename.txt
   ```

Answer (score 4):

You are just missing to make it raw. The issue is with "\". Adding r before the path would do the work :)

```
import os
os.system(r"D:\xxx1\xxx2XMLnew\otr.bat")
```

Answer (score 2):

So I do in Windows 10 and Python 3.7.1 (tested):

```
import subprocess
Quellpfad = r"C:\Users\MeMySelfAndI\Desktop"
Quelldatei = r"\a.bat"
Quelle = Quellpfad + Quelldatei
print(Quelle)
subprocess.call(Quelle)
```

Answer (score 1):

**python_test.py**

```
import subprocess
a = subprocess.check_output("batch_1.bat")
print a
```

This gives output from batch file to be print on the python IDLE/running console. So in batch file you can echo the result in each step to debug the issue. This is also useful in automation when there is an error happening in the batch call, to understand and locate the error easily.(put "echo off" in batch file beginning to avoid printing everything)

**batch_1.bat**

```
echo off    
echo "Hello World" 
md newdir 
echo "made new directory"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to call another `exe` file inside the `bat`-file.
You must use `SET Path` inside the `bat`-file that you are calling.
set Path should point into the directory there the `exe`-file is located:

```
set PATH=C:\;C:\DOS     {Sets C:\;C:\DOS as the current search path.}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your **.bat** file is in **same** directory:

```
import os
os.startfile("filename.bat")
```

You can also run Multiple **.bat** files parallelly this way

```
os.startfile("filename.bat")
os.startfile("filename2.bat")
```

-- 
If you want to change directory before running **.bat** file, run this command:

```
os.chdir("X:\directory_inwhich_the_code_will_run")
```