# bootstrap script to set environments temporarily

Tags: python, command-prompt, bootstrapping

I am trying to follow some simple instructions to use python for operating with QGIS from outside the application. Following the instructions in http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#python-applications I am stocked where it says "These commands can be put into a bootstrap script that will take care of the startup". I never done this before, I have no idea how to create this type of script...
The commands I should bootstrap are:

```
set PATH=C:\qgispath;%PATH%
set PYTHONPATH=c:\qgispath\python
```

That is, these are ways to temporarily set system environment variables. However, having both python and (of course) the cmd prompt (my OS is Win7), I have no idea how to create the bootstrap script, and then how to call it from python, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

By a bootstrap script, the documentation probably means a batch file, which initializes the path variables and then runs your application.

For instance, if you have application stored as qgis_sample.py, bootstrap_example.bat would look something like:

```
set PATH=C:\qgispath;%PATH%
set PYTHONPATH=c:\qgispath\python
python <path_to_application>\qgis_sample.py
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

For running the bat file using a python script, refer to: [Run a .bat file using python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469301/run-a-bat-file-using-python-code)

Comment: The problem is that I have to create this ".bat" file, and then call it from python, how do I do that?

Comment: Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469301/run-a-bat-file-using-python-code. Editing the answer to add this information as well.