# Using input redirection with Popen in python

Tags: python, batch-file, redirect, popen, wine

I need to use stream redirectiton in Popen call in python to use bat file with wine. I need make this:

```
wine32 cmd  < file.bat
```

It works when I run it manually from terminal, however when I try to call it from python:

```
proc = Popen('wine32 cmd < file.bat',stdout = PIPE)
```

I got error: *No such file or directory*

How to manage with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import sys

#...

with open('file.bat', 'r') as infile:
    subprocess.Popen(['wine32', 'cmd'], 
        stdin=infile, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr)
```

Make sure that each argument to `wine32` is a separate list element.

Comment: "With the default settings of None, no redirection will occur; the child’s file handles will be inherited from the parent", thus no need to have stdout, stderr there.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Ah, ok. As you might guess I haven't played with subprocess much. :) Which reminds me I really should update my old scripts that use os.popen & friends...

Comment: @jmmk: `stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr` are probably unnecessary -- test it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can check this thread.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5469427/3445802

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen("batch.bat", cwd=r"C:\Path\to\batchfolder")
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Comment: But I call it from linux through wine. Popen("file.bat" ... won't work here

Comment: are you call using idle?

Comment: What do you mean? I run python script simply via gnome-terminal

Comment: why not use idle python in ubuntu?
there .bat file can be executed with idle (because idle is the default for Windows).

I used to use it if I want to run the .bat file ... 

if the gnome terminal would be in error, because it obviously does not support the .bat file in gnome terminal.

Comment: Not ubuntu. bat may be executed using stream redirecting as I wrote. I need to get '<' stream redirect working

Comment: maybe for `Popen` module, you can try this?
`Popen(r"wine32 cmd < file.bat",stdout = PIPE)`

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried also `Popen(['wine32', 'cmd', '<', 'file.bat'], stdout = PIPE)` Then I get no errors however the code isn't run

Comment: whether to use `Popen` as you wrote has been able to call `cmd`?

Comment: `>>> import subprocess` `>>> with open('sample.bat', 'r') as filen:
 subprocess.call('wine application.exe & cmd', shell=True)`