# Activate a Conda Environment in Python Script

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, anaconda, conda

I'm converting a shell script to Python and I'm searching for a way to activate and deactivate a conda environment programmatically in Python. I've looked through the Conda code on Github and haven't been able to find a good solution.

I need the environment to be activated so that I can run multiple statements in it.  For example:

```
source activate my_env
easy_install numpy 
backup_db
initialize_db
source deactivate
```

I'm having no luck using subprocess. :-(

Comment: are you trying to activate the environment from within a Python script or as part of a bash script?

Comment: @James I'm trying to activate the environment with the Python script.

Comment: If you are trying to have the script switch to a new environment and then continue execution, that is not possible as each environment is isolated.  Each environment uses it's own kernel, so switching to a new environment necessitates starting up a new Python kernel which knows nothing about the previous computation in the script.

Answer (score 1):

A round-a-bout way of doing it, but couldn't you have python just call the script directly?

Refer to this question on how to do that

[Run a .bat file using python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469301/run-a-bat-file-using-python-code)

Comment: That would probably be my fallback plan as I would still have to extract the function and the associated variables to a different file.  Thanks for idea though.

Answer (score 1):

Linux. Was trying to create bash script to run python function from my app with test environment specifications.

```
#!/bin/bash

conda run -n test python -c 'from otp import Qod; Qod()';
```

If you have python script not in the same directory you can add sys.path absolute or relative. Planning to upgrade this script bash automation