# Activate a conda environment either in PyDev (Eclipse) or through python

Tags: eclipse, anaconda, conda, pydev, miniconda

I am using Eclipse as my python environment. I am using an anaconda environment to install all of my python interpreters and other software for this work I am doing. I have successfully pointed PyDev to the right interpreter to use (the miniconda environment one, not the system one). However, one of the functions I am using opens up a command line inside python, and this is in the wrong environment (my system environment, and not my miniconda environment). I am looking for one of two solutions:

1. Way of getting PyDev to use the Anaconda environment even for cmd line calls
2. Way of getting a python script to go into an Anaconda environment.

To make it more complex, I have limited control over the cmd line function, so cannot use the suggestion in questions such as [How do you activate an Anaconda environment within a Python Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36275308/how-do-you-activate-an-anaconda-environment-within-a-python-script) and [Activate a Conda Environment in Python Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45807042/activate-a-conda-environment-in-python-script)

Here is the code I have used so far:

```
from Bio.Blast.Applications import NcbiblastnCommandline
from io import StringIO
import os
cline = NcbiblastnCommandline( query="sequence.fa", 
  db="contigs.fa", 
  evalue=0.01, 
  outfmt=5
  )
stdout, stderr = cline()
fp = StringIO( stdout )
blast_records = [r for r in NCBIXML.parse( fp )]
```

And the error message is the following (as it is only installed in my miniconda environment)

```
Bio.Application.ApplicationError: Non-zero return code 127 from 'blastn -outfmt 5 -query sequence.fa -db contigs.fa -evalue 0.01', message '/bin/sh: 1: blastn: not found'
```

My question is as above - I am looking for one of two solutions:

1. Way of getting PyDev to use the Anaconda environment even for cmd line calls
2. Way of getting a python script to go into an Anaconda environment.

Comment: Not sure about setting up your IDE's, but you could try to add `cmd='conda run -n <name of cnonda evn> blastn'` to the `NcbiblastnCommandline`

Comment: You may want to split this into distinct questions. The behavior of an IDE's terminal (and shell) don't necessarily entail how a subprocess callout will behave. That is, you might get an answer that has the shell in the IDE terminal correctly targeting the environment, but programmatic calls to shell will start new subprocesses that may or may not inherit environment variables (i.e., the "activated" environment). What FlyingTeller suggests is also my recommendation for the problem: control the subprocess environment explicitly with `conda run`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when running in PyDev the conda env would be properly activated if you have configured to do so...

Can you check whether you have it checked there? (see screenshot below)

Some things to check if whether your `PATH` variable is actually correct by just activating the environment and that what you want to launch is there (it's also possible that what you're using for creating the command line isn't really passing the environment as expected).

[image: Load conda env vars before run]

Comment: It wasn't ticked, but ticking it didn't change the issue. Eclipse was initially installed in the non-conda environment. It is using the right interpreter, but isn't using the conda environment when command line calls are being called, and I don't know how to get around this.

Comment: I'm not sure how the env is created, but check if the `os.environ` is what you expect (the issue may be in how the cmd is being created -- if that's the case there's not much to be done in PyDev).