How can I activate a different Conda virtual environment from within a script and execute commands in that environment?
So I am trying to make a UI for my project. And the UI is built on streamlit. I have tried streamlit latest version, version 1.2.0, version 0.84.0, version 0.72.0, version 0.63.0. I am trying to create a module where I am using FILM (Frame Interpolation for Large Motion) which uses very specific dependencies. It uses tensorflow 2.6.2 and apache beam 2.34.0 which uses numpy 1.19.5. This creates compatibility issues with streamlit (I also tried gradio but same issue). So now I created a python virtual environment newenv (for streamlit) and conda film-env (for FILM). And in my script I am trying to go from newenv to film-env and back to newenv. But still FILM is not running.
It seems as though the film-env deactivates before finishing running FILM.
Please guide me for this. I need this to work soon (T T).
I have shared by function for this purpose below.
elif st.session_state.page == "processing":
st.markdown(
"""

Please Wait...

""",
unsafe_allow_html=True
)
st.title("Processing Images")
st.info("This may take a few moments...")
# Create the script to run FILM
script = """
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting script..."  # Debugging line to track script start

# Ensure Conda is initialized, if not already done
source $(conda info --base)/etc/profile.d/conda.sh  # Automatically get the base path to conda.sh
echo "Conda initialized."

# Activate the FILM environment
conda activate film-env
echo "Activated film-env."  # Debugging line

# Run FILM framework
python3 -m eval.interpolator_cli \
    --pattern "photos" \
    --model_path pretrained_models/film_net/Style/saved_model \
    --times_to_interpolate 6 \
    --output_video || exit 1
echo "FILM command finished."  # Debugging line

# Deactivate FILM environment
conda deactivate
echo "Deactivated film-env."  # Debugging line

# Activate the original Python virtual environment
source newenv/bin/activate  # Adjust path here if necessary
echo "Activated new Python virtual environment."  # Debugging line
"""

# Write the script to a file
with open("run_film.sh", "w") as file:
    file.write(script)

# Run the script with subprocess.run
process = subprocess.run("bash run_film.sh", shell=True, executable='/bin/bash', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

# Check if there was an error during FILM execution
if process.returncode != 0:
    st.error(f"Error during FILM execution: {process.stderr.decode()}")
else:
    st.success("FILM executed successfully.")

# If there are no errors, process.stdout will show output
st.write(f"Process stdout:\n{process.stdout.decode()}")
st.write(f"Process stderr:\n{process.stderr.decode()}")

# Simulate processing time
time.sleep(10)  # Adjust this duration as needed

switch_page("done")


https://stackoverflow.com/a/60523131/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/61295249/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=activate+conda+environment+script

In many cases it might not be necessary to activate a conda/virtual environment. Just call the binaries that are located in the environment, by their full path if necessary, for example path/to/env/bin/python.

@sinoroc conda run, see my second link.

This question is similar to: Activate a Conda Environment in Python Script. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
