# Linking a command line application to a tkinter GUI

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, command-line, command-line-interface

I am currently trying to write a User Interface for a program, that is only used via command line. It has several mandatory and optional parameters but you really only need one line to execute it. Now I am wondering how I can "link" my python script to the command line and make it execute the program when I click a "Run-Button".

I am just starting to get into TKinter and Python programming, so I need very basic instructions.

I am on a Linux-System (Ubuntu 16.10) using Python 3.5 and Tkinter.

Thank you.

Comment: You will get higher quality answers if you provide simple examples of what code you have already. If the script that you want to run is a python program then it would be more efficient to import the code in to your tkinter code and call it when the button is pressed, passing the appropriate arguments.

Comment: So do you have a script file you have written separately which consists of this command line execution and you need to know how to trigger that with tkinter?

Comment: Yes, exactly that @EthanField . I did now find the option of `os.popen(command)`.

Comment: Whilst you're not using a .bat file, this may be of some help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469301/run-a-bat-file-using-python-code

Answer (score 0):

For command line use, check this module: [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

In your GUI code

create a start Button:

```
Button(master, text='RUN', bg='green',fg='white', command=Run-Button).grid(row=0, pady=4)
```

and a function definition attached to it:

```
def Run-Button():
     subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"]) #use your command to run
```