# Problems running batch files with Python

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess, popen

I am rather new to Python and have been trying to run a .cmd file with it, but it won't run it from the correct location. My file Run_setup.cmd, is setting up another a different software with a bunch of related files and so I have sequestered them to their own folder for my sanity.

Currently I can get the .cmd file to run from the same location as my source code. I know I am messing up the file path for it with **cwd=r'%s'** based on what the documentation says, but I don't get how.

> If **cwd** is not *None*, the function changes the working directory to **cwd** before executing the child. cwd can be a str and path-like object. In particular, the function looks for executable (or for the first item in args) relative to cwd if the executable path is a relative path.

I currently have it using **cwd=r' C:\LargeFolder\Files\CorrectFolder'** based off [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469301/run-a-bat-file-using-python-code), and it seems that it works for any file path, but I can't seem to get it to work for me.

```
from subprocess import Popen

def runCmdfile():
    # File Path to source code:    'C:\LargeFolder\Files'
    myDir = os.getcwd()

    # File Path to .cmd file:      'C:\LargeFolder\Files\CorrectFolder'
    myDir = myDir + '\CorrectFolder'

    runThis = Popen('Run_setup.cmd', cwd=r'%s' % myDir)

    stdout, stderr = runThis.communicate()
```

What am I missing here, and furthermore what is the purpose of using **cwd=r' '** ?

Comment: `os.getcwd()` isn't the directory of the source code.

Comment: `cwd=r' '` it's a raw string see (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one works for me:

```
def runCmdfile():
    # File Path to source code:    'C:\LargeFolder\Files'
    myDir = os.getcwd()

    # File Path to .cmd file:      'C:\LargeFolder\Files\CorrectFolder'
    myDir = os.path.join(myDir, 'CorrectFolder')

    # Popen does not take cwd into account for the file to execute
    # so we build the FULL PATH on our own
    runThis = Popen(os.path.join(myDir, 'Run_setup.cmd'), cwd=myDir)

    stdout, stderr = runThis.communicate()
```

Answer (score 0):

the parameter is `cwd=`. The `r""` part only needs to exist in the definition of your string, to have a raw string and make python ignore special sequences using backslashes.

Since your string comes from `os.getcwd`, you don't need it.

```
def runCmdfile():
    # File Path to source code:    'C:\LargeFolder\Files'
    myDir = os.getcwd()

    # File Path to .cmd file:      'C:\LargeFolder\Files\CorrectFolder'
    myDir = os.path.join(myDir, 'CorrectFolder')

    runThis = Popen('Run_setup.cmd', cwd=myDir)

    stdout, stderr = runThis.communicate()
```

Comment: When using your code I keep getting the error 'FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified'. I don't know why it can't find the file as  I have confirmed it is in the right folder.

Comment: @NeverSundae does `print(myDir)` right before `runThis ...` really show the correct path? you may try even a `print('*'+myDir+'*')` to detect leading/trailing blanks etc.

Comment: @ack I tried printing like you suggested, but there are no blanks.

Comment: @nosklo  I seemed to have solved my problem, does anyone know why this seems to work?: 

runThis = Popen('C:\LargeFolder\Files\CorrectFolder\Run_setup.cmd')

Answer (score 0):

Your error is due to not escaping your \.
You need to escape your "\" where you're adding in your subfolder and then you should be good to go.

```
myDir = myDir + '\CorrectFolder'
```

should be

```
myDir = myDir + '\\CorrectFolder'
```