# Send a string as a parameter in python subprocess

Tags: java, python, maven, batch-file

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13803538/8625512) answer I can execute the `.bat` file in Python. Is it possible not only execute `.bat` file, but also send a string as a parameter, which will be used in Java programm?

***What I have now:***

*Python script:*

```
import subprocess

filepath="C:/path/to/batch/myBatch.bat"
p = subprocess.Popen(filepath, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print p.returncode # is 0 if success
```

*Java programm:*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
}
```

***What I want to have:***

*Python script:*

```
import subprocess

parameter = "C:\\path\\to\\some\\file.txt"
filepath="C:/path/to/batch/myBatch.bat"
p = subprocess.Popen(filepath, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, parameter)

stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print p.returncode # is 0 if success
```

*Java programm:*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
    System.out.println(args[1]); // prints 'C:\\path\\to\\some\\file.txt'
}
```

So the main idea is to send a string from python as parameter to a java programm and use it. What I have tried is following:

```
import os
import subprocess

filepath = "C:\\Path\\to\\file.bat"
p = subprocess.Popen(filepath, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
grep_stdout = p.communicate(input=b"os.path.abspath('.\\file.txt')")[0]
print(grep_stdout.decode())
print(p.returncode)
print(os.path.abspath(".\\file.txt"))
```

*Output:*

```
1
C:\\path\\to\\file.txt
```

`1` means, that something went wrong. And it is so, because Java programm looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String s = args[1];
    // write 's' to a file, to see the result
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\path\\to\\output.txt");
    byte[] strToBytes = s.getBytes();
    outputStream.write(strToBytes);
    outputStream.close();
}
```

and after execution `file.bat` in Python, `output.txt` is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's a [RTFM](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)-kind of answer ... you must call Popen with a list containing the "executable" and every single parameter something like`p = subprocess.Popen([filepath,os.path.abspath('.\\file.txt')], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)`. You can use `communicate` if the called "program" reads from `stdin`.

Comment: Not understanding why you need a `batch-file`?

Comment: @Squashman I am becoming this file when call `mvn clean package` command

Comment: @LohmarASHAR thank you for feedback! I will try your suggestion and tell you if it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are calling `subprocess.Popen` in the wrong way. In order to achieve what you want, as the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) states,  `Popen` should be called with a list of strings containing the "executable" and all the other arguments separately. More precisely, in your case it should be:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([filepath, os.path.abspath('.\\file.txt')], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

As a side note, you should/would use `.communicate(...)` only when the "executable" launched "asks" for input (stdin).