# Python: cannot run command line commands

Tags: python, command-line

I try to run several simple command line commands on my system and although the code run i cannot see my window opening.

For example:

```
command = 'cmd'
os.system(command)
```

Why i cannot see my `cmd` window ? all i can see in the console window (i am using `pycharm`) is this:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.449]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\blabla\tmp>
```

I also try to open `appium` server using `command line` and i have `.bat` file that call `appium` (this is what i put into the `.bat` file and this work fine manually):

This is the path to my `.bat` file:

```
C:\tmp\scripts\start_appium.bat
```

**Command**

```
p = subprocess.Popen("start_appium.bat", cwd=r"C:\tmp\scripts")
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

And i received this `error`:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in **init**
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "C:\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
>       startupinfo)   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.4\helpers\pydev_pydev_bundle\pydev_monkey.py", line
>   536, in new_CreateProcess
>       return getattr(_subprocess, original_name)(app_name, patch_arg_str_win(cmd_line), *args) FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]
>   The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a .bat file using python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469301/run-a-bat-file-using-python-code)

Comment: But this is exactly what i try to do

Comment: Try providing the full path of the batch file, and since this is a shell script, shell=True may be needed (as indicated by the second answer). 

`p = subprocess.Popen(r"C:\tmp\scripts\start_appium.bat", shell=True, cwd=r"C:\tmp\scripts")`

Comment: OK so now i received 'appium' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file, appium is the command inside my .bat file that run fine manually

Answer (score 0):

Python documentation clearly mentions `cwd` param is not the directory to search the executives.

> If cwd is not None, the child’s current directory will be changed to cwd before it is executed. Note that this directory is not considered when searching the executable, so you can’t specify the program’s path relative to cwd.

You can refer the documentation here. 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

Also, try something like this

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("C:\tmp\scripts\start_appium.bat")
```

Comment: Very strange, this is what i received: 'appium' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: My .bat file contains only appium command which work fine manually using cmd window or manually run this .bat file, what could cause this ?

Comment: The new error looks like you need to appium's path in environment variables.