# calling subprocess.call from python file does not work

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, browserify

I have a bat file called create_bundle.bat that has only 1 line in it:

```
browserify ./index.js > ./bundle.js
```

and if I activate this file, it creates a bundle file

I would like to execute this bat file every time I run my python 3.7 code.
I have this code:

```
import subprocess
import pathlib
import os

def create_bundle():
    directory_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
    file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, "create_bundle.bat")

    with open(os.path.join(directory_path, "temp_log.txt"), "w") as f:
        subprocess.call([file_path], stdout=f, stderr=f)
```

I am getting this error:

```
(PythonEnv) C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.1\jbr\bin>browserify ./index.js  1>./bundle.js 
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.1\jbr\bin\index.js' from 'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.1\jbr\bin'
    at C:\Users\localuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:55:21
    at load (C:\Users\localuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:69:43)
    at onex (C:\Users\localuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:92:31)
    at C:\Users\localuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:22:47
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469301/run-a-bat-file-using-python-code

Comment: not really.
I wrote this code:

   p = Popen("create_bundle.bat", cwd=directory_path)
   stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

But I am getting this error:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: When I execute:
p = subprocess.Popen(filepath, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE), I get the same error from my original post

Comment: Are you sure the file path is correct? Add a `breakpoint()` before the subprocess call, and examine the `file_path`.

Comment: The path is correct.
For some reason, It looks like it searches for index .js file from 'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.1\jbr\bin\index.js' and not my current folder

Comment: Oh I see the problem now. Please change your batch file from `browserify ./index.js > ./bundle.js` to `browserify index.js > bundle.js`. If you want the `bundle.js` to be in the same folder as well.

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Comment: No.
Still, the same error from my initial post

Comment: One last thing you could do it give the absolute path in you batch file.

Comment: I give absolute path.

    directory_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()

gets the absolute path