# How to execute program or batch file?

Tags: python, command-line, pycharm, windows-10

I have installed **PyCharm** to using **Python** language on **Windows 10**.

I'm trying to execute command from Linux command in PyCharm, I used this code:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run("cat",shell=True,text=True)
```

But I get this error:

> 'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,  operable program or batch file.

I want to execute several commands another such as this example, but all commands raise the same error. How to solve this?

Comment: `cat` *isn't* a windows/DOS program. In other words, if you type `cat` into the CMD prompt directly, you'll get the same result. In that sense, your python script is working as desired.

Comment: If running a command [on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5469301) or running a command [on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3777301) you have to use different approaches. Your example would run on Linux but has to be changed to run on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Cat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29) is a binary included in Unix systems, since windows isn't based on Unix, it wouldn't work. You should rather try the [`TYPE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/type) command in Windows