# Running the gcloud compute scp command in a Python script

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, automation

I want to copy a file from my Windows host machine to my Google compute instance every few seconds (basically overwrite it). To do this, I want to write a Python script that can run the compute scp command every few seconds. However I cannot seem to find any documentation on how to embed and run the command in a Python script.

Comment: Hi there! Is it possible for you to add an user to the VM and SCP to the VM using ssh-keys? Or what constraints forces you to use gcloud?

Comment: If you can use ssh-keys, take a look to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250283/how-to-scp-in-python

Comment: You do not embed the command in your Python program. The CLI **gcloud** on Windows is a batch (gcloud.cmd) file that launches a Python program. Refer to this question on how to run a batch file from Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469301/run-a-bat-file-using-python-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use Python's [`os.subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) command to execute shell commands (including `gcloud`) from within Python.

You'll need to ensure that your script access the appropriate ssh keys per the comments.

[`gcloud compute scp`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp) is a wrapper around the underlying Linux `scp` command and it may be better to use `scp` directly in this case.

It would be better still to use a Python library|package (see [PyPi: scp](https://pypi.org/search/?q=scp) that enables you to write Python native code that interacts with the scp protocol directly. This approach provides much better control of the process including error handling.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working. For anyone else who comes to this question, I used paramiko to transfer files to the cloud instance.