# how to run a .bat file in python?

Tags: python, batch-file

> > > call python 'D:\chan.bat'

"set of python statements is stored in notepad and saved as .bat extension.
how to run these statements in python.what can be the syntax?"

Comment: This topic has been already discussed here.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818774/python-subprocess]

Comment: Are you saying that you have a Python script (composed of Python statements) or a shell script (composed of command-line operations)?

Comment: Please clarify your post. What language is your .bat file written in?

Answer (score 7):

I think this is usually done using the [**subprocess**](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module:

```
from subprocess import call
call("D:\chan.bat")
```

However a normal [call](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) doesn't give you back much information. You might need the power of a [Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) object:

```
from subprocess import Popen
Popen("D:\chan.bat")
```

**Edit:**
You might need to take out the single quotes for this to work.

`"'D:\chan.bat'" -> "D:\chan.bat"`

Comment: Use `'\\'` for escaping the slash.

Comment: or use a raw string by prefixing the string with the `r` character like `r'my string here'`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to interact with the script, wouldn't this work?

```
import os
os.system("d:\\chan.bat")
```

Comment: Calling the program through the shell is usually not required; see http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system

Answer (score 2):

I have no Windows box to test it.

Here is what I try on Mac OS

```
Dinh-Phams-MacBook-Pro:tmp dinhpham$ cat > t.bat
print "abc" 
Dinh-Phams-MacBook-Pro:tmp dinhpham$  
Dinh-Phams-MacBook-Pro:tmp dinhpham$ python t.bat
abc
```

Python interpreter does not care about .py extension

If you want to load .bat file as Python module, just use

```
imp.load_source(path_to_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Command can be passed to python as follows:

```
[avasal@avasal]$ python -c "print 'a' + 'b'"
ab
[avasal@avasal]$
```

In `python --help` you can see, `-c cmd : program passed in as string (terminates option list)`, In your batch file, you can make use of this option.