# simulate a user cmd command using python

Tags: python, windows, cmd, exe, py2exe

I am trying to create exe files while my program is runing

I am trying to do so by writing .py file with code in python and the use the package py2exe for creating the exe.

my problem is that I want the proceeder will be automaticly (without the user had to open cmd and run the setup file)

manually I know how to do it using py2exe

and if I could send cmd command from code it will be perfect!

any suggestions how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a .bat file as described here:
[How can I run a program from a batch file without leaving the console open after the program start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324539/how-can-i-run-a-program-from-a-batch-file-without-having-the-console-open-after)

Put the commands you want in the bat file, and then run it using python like described here:
[Executing a subprocess fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818774/executing-a-subprocess-fails)

Comment: Thank you it really solved my problem!
this solution even fit for other problems I had , so really thank you(:

Answer (score 0):

Try using this: http://www.pyinstaller.org/

Should fit your use-case perfectly.

Comment: thank you! but didn't answer my need
this package seems awesome but still require to use cmd,
I read the whole manual and no remark to use in code for this..