# Execute batch file using Python script

Tags: python, batch-file

I'm trying to execute a batch file using a Python script. Is this possible? The Python script is in a different folder than the batch file. For example, the Python script is in `C:\users\me\desktop\python` while the batch file is in a folder `C:\users\me\desktop\batch`. I prefer not to use the full path to the batch file because I want it to work on other people's computer as well (i.e. the `C:\users\me` part might be different).

This is the script I tried (executed from the "python" folder on desktop)

```
from subprocess import call

path = "..\batch"
call([path+"\test.bat"])
```

Result: file not found

Comment: Possible duplicate of (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469301/run-a-bat-file-using-python-code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a .bat file using python code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469301/run-a-bat-file-using-python-code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing a subprocess fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818774/executing-a-subprocess-fails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslash escapes special characters in python. Therefore, the paths that you are creating here are not the ones you think they are:

```
In [1]: test = "..\bfoo"

In [2]: test
Out[2]: '..\x08foo'
```

Use raw strings instead:

```
In [3]: test = r"..\bfoo"

In [4]: test
Out[4]: '..\\bfoo'
```

And actually, the best way to combine path segments in python is by using `os.path.join`. This will automatically take care of the backslash vs. slash issues for Unix-lie vs. Windows operating systems.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However, when I run the Python script, it now shows me the code inside the batch file without actually executing it?

Comment: On the command line? Or does it open a new window. However, this is probably actually a different question.

Comment: Yes it shows the code on the command line and doesn't open a new window.

Comment: When I put the Python script in the same folder as the batch file, it works. But for some reason it doesn't work from a different folder.

Comment: Have a look at the marked duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818774/executing-a-subprocess-fails. Maybe it solves the issue?

Comment: I don't really understand what they're trying to do there, but my code is the same so I don't understand?

Comment: Maybe executing `cmd.exe /c your.bat` helps?

Comment: I'm trying now to just include the command in the Python script instead of a separate batch file. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Would be nice if you could vote or accept the answer, as it resolves the original problem of the code that you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html),

```
import os 

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))  # get the full path of the Python file
parent_dir = os.path.dirname(dir_path)

new_path = os.path.join(parent_dir, 'bath', 'test.bat')
```