# How can I run batch commands through python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file

So I have a batch file. I want to add the batch commands from the batch file to my main python file.
How can I do that? Is there a pip module for that?

Here's the batch code I want to add to the main python file:

```
@ECHO OFF
title TOG6 Spoofs


SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:menuLOOP

echo.--------------
echo.- TOG6 Spoofs -
echo.--------------
echo.
for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=_ " %%A in ('"findstr /b /c:":menu_" "%~f0""') do echo.  %%B  %%C
set choice=
echo.&set /p choice= Please select your choice:  ||GOTO:EOF
echo.&call:menu_%choice%


::-----------------------------------------------------------
:: menu functions follow below here
::-----------------------------------------------------------

:menu_1   Spoof HDD Serial

SET CurrentDir=%~dp0
echo.Mapping Driver.
%CurrentDir%mapper.exe spoofer.sys
echo.Driver Mapped. HDD serial has been successfully changed.
pause
cls
```

Thanks! :-)

Comment: This site is not a free software programming or implementation service! Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and learn [ask] here!

Answer (score 0):

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818774/executing-a-subprocess-fails) will help you but in short you'd do something like this:

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen("batch.bat", cwd=r"C:\Path\to\batchfolder")
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

If you wanted to get output from the batch file you can get that in the stdout.